# Javascript inside php code not displaying

Tags: php, javascript

I have inside my php code

```
var_dump($var);

$var ='
<script type="text/javascript">
    '.$var.'
</script>'
;

var_dump($var);
```

The first `var_dump` displays correctly some value, but the second displays an empty string.

[Exemplary output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IdpgMo):

> **Notice:** Undefined variable: var in **/code/IdpgMo** on line **3**
>   NULL
>   **Notice:** Undefined variable: var in **/code/IdpgMo** on line **7**
>   string(50) " " PHP Notice: Undefined variable: var in /code/IdpgMo on line 3 PHP Notice: Undefined variable: var in /code/IdpgMo on line **7**

Why is it so?

Comment: right click - view source

Comment: You might need to escape the variable.

Comment: empty string? You sure see a zero inside the brackets before the quotes?

Comment: "*Notice: Undefined variable: var in /code/IdpgMo on line 3*" should be pretty self explanatory, but there *is* output. See that `string(50)`? It means $var is a string with length 50. Try this: `var_dump(htmlspecialchars($var));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your browser is handling it like it is a script.
Scripts are not shown they are run so the script is in your source not displayed on screen

Comment: @user1611830: So how would you do it then to display that?

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you are leaving the `Content-Type` header at the default and the document is being processed as HTML.

A script element has no visible effect on a page.

You can see the data by:

- Writing JS that will expose the data (you'll have to make sure it is syntactically valid JS though).
- Using a DOM inspector
- Viewing Source
- Adding `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` to the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

look at the source code of the HTML page, if it shows correctly with the var dump this should be related to a javascript syntax

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing something like this:

> string(48) " "

This is because the web browser is understanding the script tags and processing it, instead of displaying the text.

If you want to be able to see the text, use the htmlentities function, so that the special HTML characters are converted and not understood by the browser as tags:

`print htmlentities($var);`